# Error when calling function: Undefined function or variable 'gscale'

Tags: matlab, function, fft

I have following code in `MATLAB` for image processing:

```
f=imread('oooo.png');
F=fft2(f);
S=fftshift(log(1+abs(F)));
S=gscale(S);
imshow(S)
```

but MATLAB gives me an error,

> Undefined function or variable 'gscale'.

Does anyone know why this is, and how I can fix it?

Comment: You have an undefined function `gscale`! Do you intend to use the function from the [File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/41511-deprecated-light-field-toolbox-v0-2-v0-3-now-available/content/LFToolbox0.2/SupportFunctions/CornerFinder/gscale.m)? If so, is it in your searh path? And if that's the case then you're calling it with too few arguments. If you have such a file, make sure it is in the current MATLAB folder.

Comment: same problem too.